# Set different color in every column css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I am facing one problem in column-count css property. Here I have a list like this--

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
  <li>eleven</li>
  <li>twelve</li>
  <li>thirteen</li>
  <li>fourteen</li>
  <li>fifteen</li>
  <li>sixteen</li>
</Ul>
```

I have to do this like image--

[image]

I can add 4 column by following css

```
.list {
   column-count: 4
}
```

But How can I give this `red` and `white` color after one another. I can't understand this.

Note: I have to create `ul, li`. I can't change this.

Comment: Use nth:child in css

Comment: Columns don't actually exist in CSS-Columns (they are not elements). Either color the respective items using `nth-child` or try another layout method.

Comment: How can I apply `nth-child`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't know what the contents of the various li elements might be - they may take up very differing heights - you can't tell in advance which li element will be in which column.

It is therefore not safe to use nth-child other than under the most simplistic of circumstances (every li taking up the same space).

A different method is to set a background image on the ul element which has 'stripes' red and white going across each taking 25% of the width. The coloring is thus responsive.

```css
.list {
  column-count: 4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 0 25%, red 25% 50%, white 50% 75%, red 75% 100%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
  <li>eleven</li>
  <li>twelve</li>
  <li>thirteen</li>
  <li>fourteen</li>
  <li>fifteen</li>
  <li>sixteen</li>
</Ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a different layout method instead of `column-count: 4` because you can't use `odd` `even` functionality here and have to define `color` value to individual column created using `nth:child`

```css
.list {
  column-count: 4;
}

.list :nth-child(n+5) {
  background: #FF0705;
}

.list :nth-child(n+9) {
  background: blue;
}

.list :nth-child(n+13) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
  <li>eleven</li>
  <li>twelve</li>
  <li>thirteen</li>
  <li>fourteen</li>
  <li>fifteen</li>
  <li>sixteen</li>
</ul>
```

A simple approach to 4 columns but you can look into `display: flex` property too.

```css
#list {
  display: flex;
}

div span {
  display: block;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #FF0705;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div>
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
    <span>three</span>
    <span>four</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>five</span>
    <span>six</span>
    <span>seven</span>
    <span>eight</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>nine</span>
    <span>ten</span>
    <span>eleven</span>
    <span>twelve</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>thirteen</span>
    <span>fourteen</span>
    <span>fifteen</span>
    <span>sixteen</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What layout should I use. Please suggest me. Where I can add `odd` and `even` functionality?

Comment: Using `display: flex` or `grid` will be easy for alignment purpose according to need @LaryJohn

Comment: Can I add `flex` or `grid` for my given example. Please Add that also in your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: But here one problem. I am getting data from backend. Here it not fixed data(16). Here Item can be 20 or 25 or any number. Then How can I add it.

Comment: @LaryJohn you must wait, as someone might not always be online. Well if that is the case  (not fixed amount known), than use `display: flex` and divide the columns in parts with some tag and than you are good to use `odd/even` but A Haworth provided a good solution applicable in all case but u must know the width and change accordingly in gradient